# I was trying to run my POM.xml from jenkins but browser is not launching but it's launching successfully from eclipse

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

When I was executed POM.xml from eclipse manually it's executing successfully but when I trigger from Jenkins it is showing message like this

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a) on port 12036
Only local connections are allowed.[INFO] Detected dialect: OSS"  but browser is not launching.
```

Anyone could please look into this issues it would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: You do not execute a pom.xml.  That is a configuration declaration for a maven project.  Need more information, such as command you are running, and your pom.xml config

Answer (score 0):

The message that you are seeing is quite normal, when you startup Selenium. It does not mean that it failed.

Usually one configures Selenium tests on Jenkins to run headlessly for most Jenkins systems do not run on a system with a display service (e.g. X server). So running your tests might actually work even if you can't see the browser starting up.